# Completion product is product of completions

Tags: metric-spaces, complete-spaces

Let $X,Y$ be metric spaces and $\tilde{X}, \tilde{Y}$ their completions. Is it true that $\tilde{X} \times \tilde{Y}$ is the completion of $X \times Y$? Here both these products have the product metric/topology. I guess this can be proven using the universal property of the completion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed it can. Since $\overline X\times\overline Y$ is complete and since the natural inclusion from $X\times Y$ into $\overline X\times\overline Y$ is distance-preserving and its range is dense, $\overline X\times\overline Y$ is indeed a completion of $X\times Y$. That's so because, if $Z$ is a complete metric space and $f\colon X\times Y\longrightarrow Z$ is uniformly continuous, $f$ can be extended to one and only one continuous function $F\colon\overline X\times\overline Y\longrightarrow Z$: if $(x,y)\in\overline X\times\overline Y$, you take a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ of elements of $X$ ande a sequence $(y_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ of elements of $Y$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n=y$ and you define$$F(x,y)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n,y_n).$$

Comment: Nice proof! If I understand correctly, you check that $\overline{X} \times \overline{Y}$ satisfies the universal property of the completion of $X \times Y$ and since this universal property determines the completion of $X \times Y$ uniquely (up to isometric isomorphism), we can conclude. Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct!

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I'm a bit confused by this answer. Isn't it enough to note that $\overline{X}\times \overline{Y}$ is complete and that $X \times Y$ isometrically embeds in $\overline{X}\times \overline{Y}$ with dense image? This is just checking the definition of completion. I'm not sure why you use the universal property. What am I missing?

Comment: @MathQED The definition of completion of a metric space $(X,d_X)$ that I am using here is: it's a pair $\bigl((Y,d_Y),\iota\bigr)$ where $(Y,d_Y)$ is a complete metric space and $\iota$ is an isometry from $(X,d_X)$ into $(Y,d_Y)$ such that, for every uniformly continuous map $f$ from $(X,d_X)$ into a complete metric space $(Z,d_Z)$, there is one and only one uniformly continuous map $F\colon Y\longrightarrow Z$ such that $F\circ\iota=f$.

Comment: Ah you take the universal property as a definition. Thanks for clarifying. So it would be correct to also observe that $X \times Y$ isometrically embeds in $\overline{X}\times \overline{Y}$ with dense image?

Comment: @MathQED Yes, since it follows from the definition that if $Z$ isometrically embeds in a complete space $Z^\star$, then $Z^\star$ is a completion of $Z$ (or, to be more precise, $(Z,\iota)$ is a completion of $Z$, where $\iota$ is an isometric embedding of $Z$ into $Z^\star$).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying again. (+1)